# How to make binning consistent in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

When I produce a histogram in R and I set the code:

```
hist(newDF2$Gaps.Res., breaks = 10, main=title1,xlab='Gaps/Residue',ylab='Count',xlim=c(0,0.5))
```

I get inconsistent binning if I change the input data as can be seen in the following plots where the first one is incorrect with 25 bins but the second one is correct with 10 bins as was specified in the code.

[image]

[image]

Why is it doing this and how can I get the number of bins to be consistent?

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:matplotlib]? That's a python plotting engine ...

Comment: You likely made a typo and didn't specify breaks in the first one. Otherwise, please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing a single value as the break; you need to provide a vector of what you want the breaks to be. Your question didn't include reproducible data, but something like below may work:

```
hist(newDF2$Gaps.Res., breaks = seq(0, 0.5, 0.1), 
     main = title1, xlab = 'Gaps/Residue', 
     ylab = 'Count', xlim = c(0, 0.5))
```

This is because if you provide a single value, R interprets that as the number of cells for the histogram, but as the documentation states:

> ... the number is a suggestion only; as the breakpoints will be set to `pretty` values

To demonstrate, say you have these data:

```
set.seed(12345)
a <- rpois(100, lambda = 4)
b <- rpois(100, lambda = 2)
```

The plots would be the same size bin with (desired output):

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
### Vecor of integers
hist(a, breaks = seq(0, 10, 1), 
     main = "Test A [breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)]", 
     xlab = 'Gaps/Residue', ylab = 'Count', xlim = c(0, 10))

hist(b, breaks = seq(0, 10, 1), 
     main = "Test B [breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)]",
     xlab = 'Gaps/Residue', ylab = 'Count', xlim = c(0, 10))
```

[image]

But if you just have a single value, you'll see the issue your facing and as outlined in the documentation:

```
# Single value
hist(a, breaks = 10, 
     main = "Test A [breaks = 10]",
     xlab = 'Gaps/Residue', ylab = 'Count', xlim = c(0, 10))

hist(b, breaks = 10, 
     main = "Test B [breaks = 10]",
     xlab = 'Gaps/Residue', ylab = 'Count', xlim = c(0, 10))
```

[image]